# What types of integrations are offered by BlueSnap?

Tags: e-commerce, bluesnap

I hear a lot about BlueSnap as a potential Payment Gateway for merchants like me, does anyone know what kind of account integrations the offer?

Comment: do you mean this https://home.bluesnap.com/partners/

Comment: I actually meant how merchants can integrate with BlueSnap, like what kind of accounts I can create, but I got the answer for that already.

The page you sent me is also very interesting, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the integration options in [this page](http://support.bluesnap.com/docs/getting-started), the main questions you should ask yourself are whether you'll need to work with a product catlog or not - and whether you have the resources to develop with the API solutions.

If you're already using shopping carts, you can integrate Magento, PrestaShop or WooCommerce with BlueSnap.